# Merging Sonatype Nexus Repository Volumes for Maven and NPM Artifacts

Tags: docker-volume, sonatype, nexus3, npm-package, artifact

My requirement is I'm building an application that uses both Maven and npm dependencies. For npm, I leverage a Sonatype Nexus3 proxy repository containing numerous artifacts. To optimize build performance and to reduce the issues, I utilize a proxy-repo to cache dependencies and ship the entire Nexus volume for later use. Because, I don't have internet in my machines.

Now I need to add some more npm artifacts into nexus repo.,(example to fix bugs, patch releases), I need to append to my actual setup from another nexus volume which having these artifacts created in my build machine. I am using docker volume to store the nexus artifacts.

However, when attempting to merge the volume of the patched Nexus data into the original one, I encountered issues where the new data overrides the existing.

I've explored options like extracting only the blob storage, but unfortunately, it doesn't reflect the changes appropriately.

How can I effectively merge Nexus repository volumes in situations like these? Are there any workarounds or best practices I should consider to manage such updates and merges seamlessly? Any insights or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

I read like, merging of volumes also gets inconsistency of versions of the artifacts, but I need to do it in any other way. And also, this nexus npm artifacts contain lot of public packages.

I also tried npm publish, but it is having issues for publishing, so I used to store the artifacts in  nexus proxy repo and using that.